# How to get the x, y, on a specific form.

Tags: c#, drawing

I'v been making a program where the user clicks, and wherever they drag their mouse, it draws a line to. It works, but it draws the lines in the wrong place. I think its because I am getting the x y of the whole form, not my panel. Heres the code:

```
 private void panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        vars.x = MousePosition.X;
        vars.y = MousePosition.Y;
        label1.Text = vars.x + ", " + vars.y;
        vars.isDrawing = true;
    }
    private void panel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (vars.isDrawing == true)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                int x2 = MousePosition.X;
                int y2 = MousePosition.Y;

                Random randomGen = new Random();
                Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(randomGen.Next(255), randomGen.Next(255), randomGen.Next(255));
                Pen line = new Pen(randomColor, 1);
                System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = panel2.CreateGraphics();
                formGraphics.DrawLine(line, vars.x, vars.y, x2, y2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its best to use an Image control instead of a panel control for this. Then you can have a seperate draw method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.X` and `e.Y` instead of `MousePosition.X` and `MousePosition.Y`

Comment: yeah it said that i had to wait